# Error "request for member 'nombreIntr' in 'jugadorActual'"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a class for the player, then the object and the idea is to make the bottom cin save what he writes in the variable "name", but when executing it says that the variable "intr" has not been declared.

```
class jugador{

    public:
    string nombreIntr(string intr);
    private:
    string nombre;
};

string jugador::nombreIntr(string intr){

    nombre = intr;
    return nombre;

}

main(){

    jugador jugadorActual();

    //G
    cout << "G: Bienvenido Jugador!\n\nG: Me dirias tu nombre?\n\n";
    //Introducir Nombre
    cin >> jugadorActual.nombreIntr(intr);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! When posting your code, please begin **each** line with additionnal 4 spaces to put it in the good format !

Comment: I don't get what your question is. "why isn't running" is a far cry from a proper problem description or question.

Comment: English questions only please. Or move to the appropriate language specific version of SO

Comment: `jugador jugadorActual();` is a function declaration, remove the `()` to create an object

Comment: i did it...still sends "intr" was not deckared in this scope

Comment: That's because you didn't declare any variable called `intr` in `main` or global scope - the error is very clear about this

Comment: string jugador :: nombreIntr (  string intr  <-- here it is) {

Comment: No, that is a function parameter - it's not a variable in the scope of `main`

Answer (score 0):

> `cin >> jugadorActual.nombreIntr(intr);`

This says to take data from `cin` and put it into whatever `nombreIntr` returns. Since `nombreIntr` returns a temporary object (a copy of the `nombre` member), this is rather ineffective (even if it had compiled).

The simplest approach to what you want to do is probably to break this statement into its two conceptual parts: get a value from `cin` and store that value in `jugadorActual`.

```
cout << "G: Bienvenido Jugador!\n\nG: Me dirias tu nombre?\n\n";
std::string nombre;
cin >> nombre;  // Get the value.
jugadorActual.nombreIntr(nombre); // Store the value.
```

There are ways to combine this into one step, but the ways I'm thinking of would require expanding the `jugador` interface, so not as simple as the above.